# Loop new slides in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

I’m trying to automate the generation of slides in the new and nice preview-version of RStudio (.rpres). The following code generate the slides, but the plots do not appear on slide 3 and onwards. How can also the plots be included?

````
My First Presentation
========================================================
author: Me
date: Now

Slide 1
========================================================
This is plot 1

```{r, echo=FALSE}
tmp.cars <- cars
tmp.cars$dist <- tmp.cars$dist*1  # Multiplied by 1 because slide 1
plot(tmp.cars)
```

Slide 2
========================================================
This is plot 2

```{r, echo=FALSE}
tmp.cars <- cars
tmp.cars$dist <- tmp.cars$dist*2  # Multiplied by 2 because slide 2
plot(tmp.cars)
```

```{r loop, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
for(i in 3:10) {
  cat(paste("Slide ", i, "\n", sep=""))
  cat("========================================================\n")
  cat(paste("This is plot ", i, "\n\n", sep=""))
  tmp.cars <- cars
  tmp.cars$dist <- tmp.cars$dist*i  # Multiplied by i because slide i
  plot(tmp.cars)
}
```
````

Comment: Isn't there is an RStudio support facility?

Comment: Yeah, maybe I should ask there. I'm thinking it could be more a Markdown-question though.